# let J(A) be the Jordan form of A. and let f be some polynomial. is it true that $\det(xI-f(A))=\det(xI-f(J(A))$

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

I tried a couple of examples and it turned out to be true, but I couldn't prove it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $A = S J(A) S^{-1}$, where $S$ is the appropriate matrix changing the basis; therefore 
$$ A^k = S \big(J(A)\big)^k S^{-1}$$
$$f(A) = S f(J(A)) S^{-1}$$and
\begin{align} \det (xI - f(A)) &= \det \big(x S S^{-1} - S f(J(A)) S^{-1}\big) = \\
&= \det(S)\det \big(x I  - f(J(A))\big)\det( S^{-1}) =\\&= \det \big(x I  - f(J(A))\big) \end{align}